# Align split base 64 parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, split, base64

Here, I have split the base 64 image into 4 different parts and it works fine. But I'm struck where I have to align the base64 as same as its base64 image. I have also attached the picture of the actual image and the split image.

[image: Actual Base64] 
[image: Split Base64]
And also I have attached the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pzwkxvq0/

```
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'), // In memory canvas
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        parts = [], // to push into oud base64 strings
        img = new Image();

    function split_4() {

        var w2 = img.width / 2,
            h2 = img.height / 2;

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            var x = (-w2 * i) % (w2 * 2),
                y = (h2 * i) <= h2 ? 0 : -h2;

            canvas.width = w2;
            canvas.height = h2;

            ctx.drawImage(this, x, y, w2 * 2, h2 * 2); // img, x, y, w, h
            parts.push(canvas.toDataURL()); // ("image/jpeg") for jpeg

            //>> JUST FOR DEMO
            var slicedImage = document.createElement("img")
            slicedImage.src = parts[i];
            var div = document.getElementById("test");
            div.appendChild(slicedImage);
            //<< JUST FOR DEMO
        }
        console.log(parts);
    };

    img.onload = split_4;
    img.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
```

Comment: in CSS `#test { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; width: 260px; }`

Comment: Thats the answer @Thomas. Post that in answer I'll upvote it